# How to make a screenshot of a webpage in python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of a webpage in python. With firefox,

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox('/Users/user_name/Downloads/geckodriver')
browser.get('http://www.google.com/')
browser.save_screenshot('screenie.png')
browser.quit()
```

I get the error msg:

```
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Users/user_name/Downloads/geckodriver'
```

despite the fact that the path is true.
I have then tried it with chrome,

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user_name/Downloads/chromedriver') #('/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://pythonspot.com');
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png");
```

and I get the error msg (mac pop up):

```
"chromedriver" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
```

Unfortunately, I also get an error with msedge

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
filename = 'f_map.html'
MyBrowser = webdriver.Edge(r"/Users/user_name/Downloads/edgedriver_mac64/msedgedriver")
murl = r'file:\\{path}\{mapfile}'.format(path='/Users/user_name/Documents/',mapfile=filename)
MyBrowser.get(murl)
sleep(10) #this is not strictly necessary but is here in case you need time for map tiles to load
MyBrowser.save_screenshot('file_name.png')
MyBrowser.quit()
```

In this case, I get :

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

Any hints will be welcome.